# javascript onclick with animation and iframes

Tags: javascript, animation, iframe, youtube, onclick

First of all, I'm not an expert in web development !

I need some help to improve my little web application.

You can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/s9ysfc2b/2/

My functions :

```
    function rollout(id) {
  var height = document.getElementById(id).height;

  if(height <= 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).height = 450;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).height = 0;
  }
}

  function videotitle(texte){

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = texte;

  }


  function go(loc) {
    document.getElementById('music').src = loc;
  }
```

The css transition :

```
iframe {
  transition: 0.3s height;
}
```

The html

```
<body>
  <div id="txt"></div>
  <iframe id="music" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>


  <form method="post">
    <input name="musicSelection" id="1" type="button" value="" onclick="go('https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLg46y7jCyHx57PG6pE_UZ46r8PPSDCxnK'); videotitle('<h2>Coucou!</h2>'); rollout('music');" />
    <input name="musicSelection" type="button" value="" onclick="go('https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLg46y7jCyHx6TNKaZ3auFYw5fT0qWiw67'); videotitle('<h2>C\'est moi...</h2>'); rollout('music')" />
    <input name="musicSelection" type="button" value="" onclick="go('https://www.youtube.com/embed/Di78xYSR0T0?list=PLO-2Biv8vPGPkkVV7LQZUguKkbwCA6qsg'); videotitle('<h2>Tu te souviens?</h2>'); rollout('music')" />

  </form>

</body>
```

When you click on emoji, a youtube video is rolling out.

If you want to click on another emoji, the video is rolling in and you have to click another time on emoji to roll the video out.

How can I roll in and out the video when I click on another emoji ? Without click one time to open it and one time to close it.

Please be free to suggest what I could do to improve whatever parts of my project

(sorry for my english..)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completely started again my project in jQuery, it's easier. I don't know how to solve it in pure JS.. now it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/gf3h6a42/

```
    $(function () {
    $(".playlistTitle").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#genericTitle").text($(this).data("text"));
        $('p').text($(this).data("desc"));
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#playlist").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function() {
        if ($('#roll').is(':visible')) {
              $('#roll').slideUp();
            if ($("#roll").data('lastClicked') !== this) {
               $('#roll').slideDown();
            }
        } 
    else {
      $('#roll').slideDown();
    }
        $("#roll").data('lastClicked', this);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function() {  
        $('.button').not(this).removeClass('buttonactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonactive');
    });
});
```